# How to inject child element with particular directive as template into parent component?

Tags: angular, dart

Im using Dart 2.4 with coresponding AngularDart.

What I want is to allow to specify optional template in my component that would be used to alter components view.

What I use:

```
@Directive(selector: "[myMarker]")
class MyDirective{
  MyDirective(Element el) {
  }
}
```

In template:

```
<my-component>
   <template myMarker>Ooo yeah!</template>
</my-component>
```

and in `MyComponent`

```
  @ViewChild(MyDirective)
  TemplateRef myTemplate;
```

however `myTemplate` is null. Im checking that with `{{myTemplate!=null}}` on template so it is lifecycle independent check i think.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ContentChild` **instead of** `ViewChild` ?

Comment: Interesting - will check that out right away

Comment: Alright! Did it work?

Comment: Yes that was the issue (+ some other followups) - Once in the past i had the same issue and totally forgot tha @ViewChild is in context of component template . Thanks. Make Answer ill acceppt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `ContentChild` instead of `ViewChild`.

[Here](https://medium.com/@tkssharma/understanding-viewchildren-viewchild-contentchildren-and-contentchild-b16c9e0358e) is a great article which explains these terms.